# sailsjs global context for a requests

Tags: sails.js

Is there a way such that I could infer a context for a given request?

For example, when an request goes into my controller, that controller will invoke a bunch of different stuff.

For almost all requests, it is guaranteed that there is a currentUserId and a currentUserDoc from mongodb.

Is it possible for me, to not have to pass those information all over the place. And instead, keep them in some kind of context object in sails? So that I can simply read that context object to infer what the currentUserId or currentUserDoc is.

Is there a feature like this that is possible with sailsjs?

Thanks

Comment: Just add it to the users session no?

Answer (score 1):

I see what you are asking for, but if you think it through, you may realize it's not a good idea.

To make it concrete, imagine that your controller method calls some helper method called `getNotifications` that fetches all the notifications for the current user. Right now when you use this method, you have to do it like this:

```
getNotifications(req.currentUserId)
```

but you want to use it like this

```
getNotifications()
```

and have the helper method determine the correct user from some sort of global object.

The reason that won't work is that there could be a few requests all coming into your controller method at once from users out in the wild, each with a different `req` instance and `currentUserId`. How would you choose which one to assign to your global object?

Since your helper method is meant to be used for a specific request, you need to pass info from that request (or the request itself) into the method. It may be annoying to code, but passing object references to helper methods really shouldn't slow things down in at all in terms of processing time.

Comment: I understand what you mean. I used work in a place where they abused process.domain as the context. I didn't look closely how they did it. But it was actually super reliable. Each request is somehow bind to this "domain" and that domain is globally accessible and still different for each request.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using oauth2 + bearer tokens as your security pattern, then you can add a call to your policy that checks for your valid bearer token. Since the token is 1 to 1 with your user, once you verify the token you can pull the user id and add it to the request. For the userdoc id, I assume you have a way to pull that from the request header/body then you can also add that to the request. Then your policy would hand off the request to the controller. Policies execute prior to the controller action.